# Missing certain GCDA files after test execution

Tags: c++, macos, llvm, code-coverage, gcov

I'm currently facing an issue with generating .gcda files for coverage data of a static library. I can get coverage data for most files, but not all.

I'll refer to the object file with the missing coverage data as X.

Some things to note:

- I have compiled the library and test executable with the appropriate flags.
- The .gcno files are generated for all objects, including X.
- The .gcda files are generated for MOST objects, excepting X.
- The symbol dump of X's object file has the gcov symbols present in its disassembly.

When running a test that uses X, .gcda files are generated for other files, just not X.

What could be happening that prevents a single .gcda file from being generated?

-

Operating System: OS X  10.12

LLVM Compiler Version:  8.0.0

Comment: Is the object X linked with the gcov library? Also the *.gcda files for the sources of library X would be generated in the path where the library X was build from source.

Comment: Yes. .gcda files are being generated for all objects but a few. They are all linked and built with the appropriate flags as shown in the xcodebuild output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the issue was including the suspect files in both the test project and the library project. The .gcda files were found in the test's intermediate files, but were absent from the library's intermediate files.

Strange issue, and also difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need your kernel enable for gcov.
Enable **CONFIG_DEBUG_FS, CONFIG_GCOV_KERNEL, CONFIG_GCOV_FORMAT_AUTODETECT** and **CONFIG_GCOV_PROFILE_ALL**

and the gcda file for static lib will be under /sys/kernel/debug/gcov/

Comment: How would this prevent 1 .gcda file from being generated? The information I can find for these variables is regarding code coverage of the kernel. I will try this and update you on the result.

Comment: That did not produce any further results.

Comment: Sorry, Though that you were talking about kernel static lib.

Comment: Maybe you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011222/gcov-not-generating-gcda-files