# how to generate gcda files from gcov in android

Tags: gcov

Eclipse Compilation of application, i had incorporated gcov compilation and linking flags..and generated the image where i got gcno files..

i am running this application as stand-alone on the device.. but i couldn't able to see the gcda files in the android device when i run this app..

./cractus

is there a possibility to generate the gcda files and store on the device with out getting it on host-PC ?

I tried this ..# find . -name *.gcda

but no response

Comment: This question has been asked a few times on SO, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011222/gcov-not-generating-gcda-files. Could you search and see if any are appropriate for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the branch in the destructor reported by gcov?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199360/what-is-the-branch-in-the-destructor-reported-by-gcov)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcov not generating gcda files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011222/gcov-not-generating-gcda-files)